# Sum one column where in another column the same row and row below meet conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have this table in Excel:

```
Name   Sum
a      200
b      100
a      100**
a      250
b      150
a      100**
a      300**
a      150
b       50
a      350
b      200
```

I want to sum the value of each cell opposite to `a`, but only if it is not followed by a cell `b` (as indicated**). In this example I should get `500`.

Or vice versa, only sum the cells opposite to `a`, which are followed by a `b`.

Is there any (more or less simple) way it could be done?

Comment: Is this a programming problem? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, @pnuts. The follow-up for P. Smirnov is "What have you tried so far?" Presumably Smirnov tried to solve the problem himself before asking for help, in which case he should explain what he tried in the question. Otherwise StackOverflow is just the place to come to get free VBA and regex scripts.

Comment: I think the burden is on the Questioner to show that this is a programming question, i.e. show his work, rather than Larson's.

Comment: @pnuts It sounds like you and I are in agreement on everything except for the requirement for evidence of effort, but on that point I disagree strongly. Unfortunately we're not going to persuade each other in this comment thread, so we may as well just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B11,A1:A11,"a",A2:A12,"<>"&"B")
```

[SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5):

> Syntax
>
> SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,criteria2], …)
>
> The SUMIFS function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> sum_range    Required. One or more cells to sum, including numbers or names, ranges, or cell references that contain numbers. Blank and text values are ignored.
>
> criteria_range1    Required. The first range in which to evaluate the associated criteria.
>
> criteria1    Required. The criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells in the criteria_range1 argument will be added. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, ">32", B4, "apples", or "32."
>
> criteria_range2, criteria2, …    Optional. Additional ranges and their associated criteria. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.
>
> Remarks
>
> Each cell in the sum_range argument is summed only if all of the corresponding criteria specified are true for that cell. For example, suppose that a formula contains two criteria_range arguments. If the first cell of criteria_range1 meets criteria1, and the first cell of criteria_range2 meets critera2, the first cell of sum_range is added to the sum, and so on, for the remaining cells in the specified ranges.

Comment: I'm quite intimidated by saying this to such a high rep, but maybe explain a bit how this works, and why it will help, be it only for future readers?

Comment: I never knew you could use an offset range in a sumif like this, brilliant answer pnuts.